# Token not generated on submit of card details

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have mounted the card element but still on submit click i don't get the stripe token generated instead it shows the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element.
              Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.

```
<span class="input input--filled" id="fullcard"> 
    <span id="card-element" class="input_field"></span>  
     <label class="input_label"> 
      <span class="input__label-content">Card details</span> 
     </label> 
</span>
```

Comment: I have used the demo shown in this https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart#create-token . Here I just converted the addeventlistener of form to onclick function of submit

Comment: Is the element being asked for in the example present in the dom when you trigger your onclick?